# When I copy code from oneNote to Eclipse, correct code is marked with red squiggly line and gives syntax error

Tags: java, eclipse, onenote

[image: Picture]

I tried copying the text first to notepad and then pasting it from there to get rid of possible text formatting. But still didn't work.

However, when I copy the code to the google search bar and then paste it back to Eclipse it worked.

Can someone tell me why this happens? Is there an easier way to prevent having these syntax errors when copying text from oneNote?

```
    public static void isPalidrome(String str) {
            if (str.charAt(0) != str.charAt(str.length() - 1)) {
                    System.out.println("Not a palidrome");
                }

            else if (str.length() <= 2) {
                    System.out.println("Is a palidrome");
                }

            else {
                    isPalidrome(str.substring(1, str.length() - 2));
                }
    }

}
```

Comment: in what class is that code? could you please show us the rest of the code in the file?

Comment: If you save after pasting, Eclipse understands the encoding and the errors disappear.

Comment: Trust only text editors-not even Notepad.

Comment: Like the now deleted answer correctly told you, it is an encoding issue with some non-printable chars. Either remove the line breaks and indentations manually and re-add them or try to copy the code from oneNote to something else and then eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

OneNote is very bad for keeping programming code. It inserts non-breaking space into your code. It's not visible but always causes errors when you copy it out of OneNote.

Vote this OneNote feedback to get them look into the problem: [Uservoice](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows/suggestions/37201003-why-does-onenote-insert-non-breaking-space-xc2-xa)